# Circle to sinusoidal graph

Tags: calculus, circles

I was thinking about we go from a circle to a sinusoidal plot and it's best explained [here](https://betterexplained.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/circle-two-sine-waves.gif)

From what I understand is the changes in the `y-axis` represents a `sine` wave and changes in the `x-axis` represents a `cosine` wave.

What I want to know is how do we get that sine wave? I understand that we moving on the circumference but how do I express it using equations without using trigonometry? I want to find the derivative of y w.r.t time and get that sinusoid graph.

Comment: The horizontal axis is the angle measured anticlockwise from the positive x axis, in radians. The vertical axis is the height of the point above the x axis (negative for below).

Comment: Okay. But how do I find the derivative of y wrt time which would get me that sinusoidal graph?

Comment: If you differentiate sin you get cos. Your question is a little confused, what is it you want to differentiate? Also, you don't want to use any trigonometry so I don't know what is allowed in creating the derivative. Do you want a geometric construction of the derivative of cos(x) via the circle graphic?

Comment: What I want to know is how does moving around a circle leads to a sinusoidal graph as described in the GIF. Why doesn't it form a triangle wave? From what I understand is we get a sinusoidal because of the rate of change of y-axis wrt to time. All I want to understand is the sinusoidal graph through equations.